# AWS Appsync - add multiple items

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Is there any way of connecting appsync to dynamodb with option to put multiple items at once? I'm asking about dynamodb reuqest mapping.

Let's say we have saveVotes mutation

```
type Mutation {
    saveVotes(votes: [VoteInput]): [Vote]!
}
```

How should I design dynamo request template to get each vote saved as separate object in the dynamodb? Each VoteInput has ID. I'm sending 5 VoteInput, and I want to have 5 separate object, with separate ID in the dynamodb.
In the AWS docs there are examples just for single putItem which is not enough for me
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-putitem

Comment: When you execute a single `PutItem`, does your `PutItem` operation needs a `conditionExpression`? If not, then you can use AWS AppSync `BatchPutItem` operation. There is a tutorial here on how to use it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#single-table-batch.

Comment: What's the best way to do this on current date?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at using Batch Resolvers at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html

As I understand it, you can construct your GraphQL queries to accept a collection of items and then implement the associated resolvers to perform batch operations in the way you describe.

Answer (score 1):

So the best solution for me is to make query this way

```
mutation saveVotes {
  vote1: saveVotes(author: "AUTHORNAME", value: 1 ) { author, value }
  vote2: saveVotes(author: "AUTHORNAME", value: 3 ) { author, value }
}
```

Comment: Yes this will work although you can also use a lambda function as a proxy to run a BatchWriteItem yourself. It would be very nice to be able to invoke a BatchWriteItem operation directly from a resolver.

Comment: BatchWriteItem has some limitations - The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB. - it's not enough for me, but yes, the option to call it directly from lambda would be great anyway.